# My GAE App is so Slow, A lots of "HTTP(503) from Unknown Origin" in Logs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

In the last two days my GAE App sometimes response quickly and most of the times loading so slow or loading forever.
Same application version in another domain works just fine.

I checked my logs to see any errors and I surprised with a lots of **HTTP(503) from Unknown Origin**: 
[image: screenshot here]

The error details:

[image: error in details here].

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to read the pictures, but the relevant log is:

URL: /_ah/start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleared the Memcache and the problem gone away. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Your app seems to be configured for [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/warmup-requests/). Unfortunately, your app is responding to the requests for /_ah/start with a 503, which is causing the process to be terminated (and an new process started, which will make your app seem very slow).

The relevant message is:

```
Process terminated because it failed to respond to the start request with an HTTP status code of 200-299 or 404.
```

You probably want to remove the `-warmup` from the `inbound_services:` section of your `app.yaml`, or configure a warmup handler on `/_ah/start`.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/warmup-requests/configuring

Comment: I didn't use a **warmup requests** at all, Problem Solved by resetting Memcache.
Thanks for your replay